# Angular 2 RC Final - Dynamically loading route data from service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm trying to load route data from a service and automatically generate routes in Angular 2 RC Final. I see that you can assign route data via the Router.Module.forRoot() function but don't see a way of assigning fetched data to the function. I tried the code below but get a "Property 'forRoot' does not exist on type 'RouterModule' error".

I may be completely off the mark, but the code should show roughly what I'm trying to achieve. The app paths are: mysite.com/london/ mysite.com/new-york/, etc. Is there a way of doing this?

The router version I am using is: "@angular/router": "~3.0.1"

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PathService } from './path.service';
import { Path } from './path';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    providers: [
        PathService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule implements OnInit {
    private ROUTES: Array<Object>;
    private paths: Path[];

    constructor(
        @Inject(RouterModule) private _routerModule: RouterModule,
        @Inject(PathService) private _pathService: PathService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPathData();
    }

    getPathData() {
        this._pathService.getPaths().subscribe((paths: Path[]) => this.paths = paths, (err: any) => { }, () => this.generateRoutes());
    }

    generateRoutes() {
        this.ROUTES = 'do something to this.paths and assign route date here';

        this._routerModule.forRoot(this.ROUTES);
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
[
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "London",
        path: "london"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "New York",
        path: "new-york"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        name: "Paris",
        path: "paris"
    },
    {
        id: "4",
        name: "Tokyo",
        path: "tokyo"
    }
]
```

Comment: I ended up solving my own problem by just using `path: ":city"` in the routing module. This just handles any city that is thrown at it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure as this seems very cutting edge. The closest to what you want is lazy loading routes. Heres a very simple demo. The routes are loaded when they are first visited on demand.

I doubt it helps but worth a shot :)

https://github.com/danday74/angular2-router-modular/blob/master/app/app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I'm not sure if lazy loading is what I need. In my app, I have an API which outputs the website sections in JSON format. For instance, as location names. These location names are also path names in the app URL. e.g. mysite.com/london/ and mysite.com/new-york/. I'm looking for a way to take these location names from the JSON and generate the routes for the app. The number of location names can vary and is updated in the backend of the app, which ideally would then propagate into the RouterModule automatically.

Comment: you could have mysite.com/location/:city ... if city is valid then use the location route --- if city is invalid then use the notfound component - maybe that would satisfy your needs (or redirect to not found component)

Comment: But would it be possible to set it up so there is no static data or references to locations other than the database and JSON output? Ideally, the app should be generic so there is no need to create/delete files/folders if the locations change.

Comment: i would do ... mysite.com/location/:city ... the easy implementation is go to the location route. get the city from route.params ... then do an HTTP request for the city (to get full city info) ... if 404 then redirect to NotFoundComponent else display the city ... the better alternative would be to implement logic at the router level which would prevent serving the location route if the city did not exist, saving the need for a redirect / router state (route) change

Comment: Yea, that sounds like one possible solution. The spec of our app means that I have to do mysite.com/:city. I actually just tried /:city in the route module, which the data handling in the page component .ts and it worked!